# Getting ratio column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
Country WestOrEast  Revenue
US          East       2
US          West       3
France      East       1
France      West       4
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of revenue from East from all revenue, and have it as a column like this:

```
Country WestOrEast  Revenue    East%
US          East       2         28
US          West       3         28
France      East       1         20
France      West       4         20
```

So I just need East percentage of whole revenue. I know I can transform the dataframe so it looks like this:

```
Country WestOrEast  RevenueEast   RevenueWest
US          East            2                3
France      East            1                4
```

And then calculate the `East%` easily. But is there a faster way?

Please feel free to edit my question title or anything so the question becomes better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try transform:

```
tmp = (df.assign(fromEast=df['WestOrEast'].eq('East')*df['Revenue'])
         .groupby('Country')
         .transform('sum')
      )
df['East%'] = tmp['fromEast']/tmp['Revenue']
```

Output:

```
  Country WestOrEast  Revenue East%
0      US       East        2   0.4
1      US       West        3   0.4
2  France       East        1   0.2
3  France       West        4   0.2
```

Another way, similar to what you mentioned, is to use `crosstab` and `map`:

```
tmp = pd.crosstab(index=df['Country'], columns=df['WestOrEast'],
                  values=df['Revenue'],
                  aggfunc='sum', normalize='index')

df['East%'] = df['Country'].map(tmp['East'])
```